# Doubt on Interpreting Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a doubt about interpreting this question. I will post the question and my attempt. I get two different answers.

"A box contains $3$ red balls, $4$ blue balls, and $5$ white balls. Three balls are drawn at random from the box, one by one, without replacement. Find the probability that the second red ball appears on the third draw." Hence we have $3$ red and $9$ non-red balls.

If I interpret it as an unconditional probability problem, we obtain
$$P(R_1 ~R_2' ~R_3 \cup  R_1 '~ R_2~ R_3) 
\\~\\ = P(R_1 ~R_2'~ R_3) + P(R_1 ' ~R_2~ R_3)
\\~\\  = \frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{11}\cdot \frac{2}{10}+  \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{11} \cdot \frac{2}{10} = \frac{9}{110} $$
where $R_i$ is the event of drawing a red and $R_i'$ is the event of not drawing a red on the $i$'th draw.

If I interpret it as a conditional probability problem I get
$$ P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right) \right)
\\~\\
= \frac{P(R_3~ \cap ~\left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right) ) }{P\left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right)} 
\\~\\ = \frac{P(R_1 ~R_2' ~R_3 \cup  R_1 '~ R_2~ R_3)}{P\left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right)} 
\\~\\ = \frac{P(R_1 ~R_2'~ R_3) + P(R_1 ' ~R_2~ R_3)}{P(R_1 ~R_2')  + P(R_1' ~R_2) }  
\\~\\ = \frac{\frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{11}\cdot \frac{2}{10}+  \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{11} \cdot \frac{2}{10}}{\frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{9}{11}+  \frac{9}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{11} } = \frac{1}{5}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Of course the answers are different as both your approaches answer different questions.

In first, you are answering the probability of drawing two red balls in three draws with second red ball being fetched in the third draw. This is what the question asks.

In second, you are finding the probability of a specific outcome for *only* the third ball *given* a condition on the first two balls. The specific outcome you are seeking for the third ball in this case is red and the *given* condition on the first two balls is that one of them are red. You know after two draws, you are left with $10$ balls and $2$ of them are red. So the probability of *third* ball being red is *indeed* $\cfrac{2}{10} = \cfrac{1}{5}$, which is what you got applying conditional probability.

Comment: Can you elaborate what I am finding in my first interpretation. You wrote 'the probabilty of drawing second red ball in third draw ', so then what is given here? I don't see the distinction between the first and second , english wise.

Comment: I want to disagree with your answer (respectfully), and ask why it will not be $\frac{9}{110}$. If one looks through a tree diagram, there are $2$ possible branches the condition holds true ($R-R'-R$  or $R'-R-R$), therefore you can add their probabilities up. Also, I did not quite get the understanding of "_In first, you are answering the probability of drawing second red ball in third draw_" ; I believe we are already accounting for $1$ red ball already being drawn through the $2$ possible branches - (or am I getting this wrong?)

Comment: @SnipingPoodle for the given question, $\frac{9}{110}$ is the correct answer. Sorry if it did not come across that way in my explanation. I will edit.

Comment: @john in the first, you are answering the given question. In the second, you are finding the probability of a specific outcome for only the third ball given certain conditions on first two draws.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I think that the 'conditional probability' interpretation $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right) \right)$ is equivalent to $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3~\cup~ R_1~R_2' ~R_3' \cup R_1'~R_2 ~R_3  \cup  R_1'~R_2 ~R_3' \right) \right)$ when we actually want  $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3 ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2 ~R_3 \right) \right)$. Forgive the redundancy of $R_3$.

Comment: @john but $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3 ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2 ~R_3 \right) \right)$ will be $1$, right?

Comment: because $P\left(R_3 ~\cap  \left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3 ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2 ~R_3 \right) \right)$ is $P\left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3 ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2 ~R_3 \right)$

Comment: @MathLover I see since $R_3 \cap R_3 = R_3$ so then this is not a 'conditional' probability question per se, and my attempt to cast it as such didn't work. Thus the unconditional probability interpretation is correct. 
I had a quick question, do you agree that $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right) \right)$ is equivalent to $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~R_3~\cup~ R_1~R_2' ~R_3' \cup R_1'~R_2 ~R_3  \cup  R_1'~R_2 ~R_3' \right) \right)$. This helps me think what $P (R_3 ~\mid~ ( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2 )) $ actually means. After expanding some terms go to zero.

Comment: Yes your interpretation of $P\left(R_3 ~\mid~  \left( R_1~R_2' ~\cup~ R_1'~R_2  \right) \right)$ is correct. Also yes, it is not a conditional probability question.

Comment: @MathLover I still feel somehow this is a conditional problem, isn't the condition that the first two balls there is at least one red and they can't both be non-red? 
You wrote, "finding the probability of a specific outcome for only the third ball given a condition on the first two balls"  is different than finding the probability for all 3 balls , but we imposed the condition that there is a red in the first two balls. So this is not a condition? I might be confused by the semantics of a condition , versus conditional (probability). 
So the issue is probability of one ball versus 3?

Comment: @john I am outside and should be home in an hour. We can get into a chat to clarify further if you are available then. Also read my answer on what you are finding in the first approach.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks. By the way, here is a snapshot of the full [question](https://snipboard.io/RrJXOW.jpg).
Part c) is a conditional probability question, but part c) seems similar to part d). 
I could even cast it or phrase it as such. 
For example  d) "Find the probability that the third ball is red given that there is exactly one red ball drawn in the first two draws". Would you say the latter re-phrasing is a conditional probability question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129512/discussion-between-math-lover-and-john).

Answer (score 2):

(Expanding on Math Lover's answer, which has already identified the error.)

1. In your first method, you have found this probability, as requested:
   $$P(RBR,RWR,BRR,WRR).$$

   Notice that identifying these $4$ favourable outcomes out of the
   $27$ possible ones is the simplest and most direct way to complete
   the given exercise, and that visualising the probability tree can be
   helpful.
2. In your second method, however, you are working with a **reduced
   sample space** of only $12$ outcomes,
   while excluding these $15$ outcomes from consideration:
   $$RR\_,BB\_,WW\_,BW\_,WB\_.$$ And since the favourable outcomes in this method are the same as in your first, the ensuing probability is bigger than in your first method.